# Unexpected return from cin.getline() in C++

Tags: c++, cin, getline

I have this problem that when I use getline() function to input a char array it also inserts other characters, that are not constant and change every time I run the program.

I do realize  it is most likely because  of some kind of overflow happening, and it just takes numbers from the RAM.

But is there a possibility to fix that?
(Program is supposed  to reverse  a string and remove any non-letters, excluding spaces)

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string decoded = "";
    char text[100]; 
    cin.getline(text,sizeof(text));
    for(int i = sizeof(text)-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if (isalpha(text[i]) || text[i] == ' ' )
            decoded.push_back(text[i]);
    }
    cout << decoded;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char text[100] {};`. You need to initialize the array to zero by yourself, C++ won't do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Add `#include <string.h>` and change

`for(int i = sizeof(text)-1; i >= 0; i--){` to

`for(int i = strlen(text)-1; i >= 0; i--){`

because `strlen(text)` calculates length upto `\n` where as `sizeof(text)` includes `\n` too.

or as `Ruks` mentioned in the comment a simple initialization `char text[100] {};` works.

Comment: You shouldn't use `scanf` for a string without a length specifier and without checking the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare text as an empty array same as `char[] text = new char[]{};`

Comment: That's invalid syntax.